# Variables not showing after debug and run

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't see my variables after debug and run.

[image]

I don't know how to config.

Comment: why don't you use the Microsoft Python extension

Comment: The extension has installed and enabled.

Comment: I have a new error: Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information.

Comment: i think i solve it, but not sure how it works. I init the powershell and restart the conda and vscode....it took me whole day to fix this T.T . But I am very happy it finally works! Thanks God!

Comment: remove this `geecode` extension, it has not been updated since 2019-05 and only has 1 version, why and when have you installed it, the Microsoft Python extension has 63M+ happy users